# How to invoke n times a rest service and interpret the result at the end, using retrofit and rxjava?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to process the result after invoking n times a rest service, but a list of objects of which a property tells me whether or not to invoke the web service, however I can not process the final result when finishing the n invocations, It seems that it is due to asynchrony, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?, Thank you very much, and excuse my bad English.

The example code is:

```
private List<ResquestService> request;

private void process(){
    Observable.fromIterable(request)
    .filter(resquestService -> resquestService.getType().equals(WS_TYPE))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(
            resquestService -> {consumeRestService(resquestService);},
            Throwable::printStackTrace,
            () -> {processFinalResults();}
    );
}

private void consumeRestService(ResquestService resquestService){
    getApi().processData(resquestService)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(
                    next -> {processResultWS();},
                    error -> {handleErrorWS();}
            );
}

public class ResquestService {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put in the iterable
.subscribeOn (Schedulers.newThread ())

and in the call to the rest service:
.observeOn (AndroidSchedulers.mainThread ())

```
private void process(){
    Observable.fromIterable(request)
    .filter(resquestService -> resquestService.getType().equals(WS_TYPE))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(
            resquestService -> {consumeRestService(resquestService);},
            Throwable::printStackTrace,
            () -> {processFinalResults();}
    );
}

private void consumeRestService(ResquestService resquestService){
    getApi().processData(resquestService)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    next -> {processResultWS();},
                    error -> {handleErrorWS();}
            );
}
```